# Music Transfer from Laptop to Phone for Immediate Use

Tags: music

When my music transferred from new macbook air to my iPhone 6 it seemed to become stored in the cloud rather than available to me on the phone when I want to play it and I am not always near wi-fi. I purposely purchased an iPhone 6 with 64k memory to avoid not being able to hear music and now it has happened anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Under `Settings > Music` on your iPhone, what is the position of the `iTunes Match` and `Show All Music` settings? If `Show All Music` is off, only tracks that have been recently played or explicitly downloaded from the cloud will appear in the Music app.